# Separator line showing up after selection of last row in section

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I'm seeing a weird behavior in all of my UITableView's. This is starting to drive me nuts.

I have plain styled UITableViews. The last row in the section doesn't get a separator, it just blends in to the section header (default usage by the way). Checking the height of this last row, it appears Apple is making it 1px larger to remove the separator height from the cell. The problem is when I select the row, but drag off, the separator line shows up and never goes away. If I go back a view and come back in, it defaults to off.

I'm seeing this across all of my table views, normal cells and custom cells. What can I do to make sure this last separator stays away when I cancel a selection? iOS 7 only build. Running current builds, no betas.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue now :(

Answer (score 1):

For me reloading of cell helped for some separator line problems:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: This does work, but only if you select and let go. If I select it and drag off, the line gets stuck there. Close, but not quite.

Comment: Update my answer with another function I forgot about - however than break fade out of selection ;) maybe you can try delaying it by few miliseconds.

Comment: Tried new method, but still has the same behavior. Unhighlights, the separator is there for just a split second. Seems close, but no way that delay is going to fly. I'd like to know why Apple has it this way. I'm guessing it is a bug, so I'll likely just file a radar.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the style of the tableView in the storyboard from plain to grouped, you won't get this behavior. It will give you a section header above your section though. To get rid of it, do this -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0.01f;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using storyboards, so this isn't the case.

Comment: all the storyboard properties have code equivalents you can change in code